# Is is possible to do `IN` query over JSON array?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016-express

In SQL Server, is there a way to do `IN` query over json array ?

eg.

There's a column `foo` which contains a json array

row1 -> `{"foo":["a", "b"]}`

row2 -> `{"foo":["c", "a", "b"]}`

I need to query rows which has `b` in json array

`JSON_QUERY` can return the array, but there's no way to do

Something like

```
SELECT *   
FROM table1 
WHERE "b" in JSON_QUERY(foo)
```

`LIKE` query will work, but is inefficient

Comment: How about using [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with `CROSS APPLY` and then filter that way?

Comment: @Igor - can you elaborate a bit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `OPENJSON` with `JSON_QUERY` and use `CROSS APPLY` to break down the result to the array elements level

```
declare @tmp table (foo nvarchar(max))

insert into @tmp values
('{"foo":["a", "b"]}')
,('{"foo":["c", "a", "b"]}')
,('{"foo":["c", "a", "y"]}')

SELECT foo
  FROM @tmp AS c
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(foo, '$.foo')) AS x
  where x.[value]='b'
```

Sample input:

[image]

Sample output:

[image]